# How do I run a query on a database whose name contains a space?

Tags: mysql

In MySQL I created a database with name like de mo, and it contains a table like tablename. When I try to execute a query, for example:

```
select * from de mo.tablename
```

I am not able to execute that query.  How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use backticks:

```
`de mo`
```

Answer (score 6):

You'll have to quote the database name:

```
SELECT * FROM `de mo`.tablename
```

Spaces in [identifiers](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/identifiers.html) are best avoided really.

Answer (score 0):

It is necessary to quote the name.  Usually backticks are used:

```
select * from `de mo`.tablename
```